# Forwarding Rvalue Of Derived UniquePtr Through Base Class Accepting Method Moves Reference Instead of Copying

Tags: c++, c++17

It seems that forwarding an rvalue reference to a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` through to an accepting method taking a `const std::unique_ptr&` of the base class causes that std::unique_ptr to be moved from. This does not happen with numerics or non-inheriting classes.

Originally was found on MSVC++ 2019, but also tested on various other compilers which all gave the same results. Is this behavior standard-conforming?

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{};

class NonInheriting
{};

void Corrupter(const std::unique_ptr<Base>&)
{}

void Corrupter(const std::unique_ptr<int>&)
{}

void Corrupter(const std::unique_ptr<NonInheriting>&)
{}

void Usage(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& base)
{
    assert(base);
}

void Usage(std::unique_ptr<int>&& base)
{
    assert(base);
}

void Usage(std::unique_ptr<NonInheriting>&& base)
{
    assert(base);
}

template<class... Args>
void Forwarder(Args&& ... args)
{
    Corrupter(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    Usage(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    // No assertion
    std::cout << "1\n";
    auto integer = std::make_unique<int>();
    Forwarder(std::move(integer));

    // No assertion
    std::cout << "2\n";
    auto nonInheriting = std::make_unique<NonInheriting>();
    Forwarder(std::move(nonInheriting));

    // No assertion
    std::cout << "3\n";
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    Forwarder(std::move(base));

    // Assertion
    std::cout << "4\n";
    auto derived = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    Forwarder(std::move(derived));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

For the 4th case, you're passing an `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`, in `Forwarder` it's passed to `Corrupter`, which expects `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` could convert to `std::unique_ptr<Base>` implicitly, then the parameter `args` is converted to `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, and the ownership of the pointer is transferred to the temporary `std::unique_ptr<Base>` too, `args` owns nothing now. After that it's passed to `Usage` then assertion gets triggered.

In other cases, no conversion and ownership transferring happens then they don't have such issue.

If you add another overload of `Corrupter` taking `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` exactly, i.e. to eliminate conversion and ownership transferring, then no assertion.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ebXnpYCCPtdAvlws)